# Не работает интернет на android с помощью WebView - ошибка webpage not available (net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Начинаю разбираться с android studio и писать своё приложение. Хочу сделать чтобы на главной странице подгружался нужный мне сайт всегда. Компоновал код из разных источников. Всё работает, однако страница не загружается с ошибкой net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Привожу код.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.bro1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        SimpleWebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new SimpleWebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.loadUrl("https://javadevblog.com");

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

SimpleWebViewClientImpl:

```
package com.example.bro1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class SimpleWebViewClientImpl extends WebViewClient {

    private Activity activity = null;

    public SimpleWebViewClientImpl(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {
        // все ссылки, в которых содержится 'javadevblog.com'
        // будут открываться внутри приложения
        if (url.contains("javadevblog.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        // все остальные ссылки будут спрашивать какой браузер открывать
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bro1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="Добро пожаловать!"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"-->
        <!--app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Вот такой проект. Помогите кто сможет, спасибо!

Comment: Точно этот код? Такое бывает, если грузить в вебвью что-нить из локальных файлов. Попробуйте ради интереса добавить в манифест пермишены на `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Добавил, всё так же, ничего не произошло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось с другой стороны. Всё работает. Оказывается проблема была в эмуляторе Android Studio.

Использовался - **Nexus One API 29** (он как раз и не загружал страницы - на телефоне проверил своём на последнем андроиде а там опа - всё работает)

Установил и корректно работает - **Nexus 5 API 26**

Всем спасибо, кто помог дойти до этого понимания! Респект вам!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в манифесте

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

далее

```
  <application
    android:name=".utills.MyApplication"

    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="n">
```

network_security_config:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

вот здесь:

[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где создать - network_security_config ? И android:name=".utills.MyApplication" - тут своё имя указать?

Comment: utills.MyApplication это лишнее, network_security_config  в пакете xml

Comment: То есть в layout ? Где находится активите мэйн и контент мэйн.хмл ?

Comment: я дополнил ответ

Comment: Не сработало. Всё так же

Comment: @yong попробуйте для начала загрузить заведомо рабочий сайт или просто другой

Comment: Да пробовал и гугл и яндекс всё одно и тоже и без https пробовал сайты. А я могу как то скинуть весь проект тебе? Сможешь глянуть?

Comment: оставь почту я скину адресс

Comment: modeler111@mail.ru

Comment: @yong в вашем случае, предположу, что на эмулятор не установлины сервисы гугл либо webview или типо того